# biclique cover implementations

Tags: graph-theory, heuristics, computation-theory

The [biclique cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biclique_cover) is known to be hard *and* hard to approximate. Does anyone know of any software which implements some sort of practical heuristics?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21026150/378360), you could try to reduce the problem to Clique Cover, using either the reduction from [Kou&Wong](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/361219.361225) or the one from [Nor et al.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-13509-5_19). I have written a [Clique Cover solver](http://www.user.tu-berlin.de/hueffner/ecc/) with both an exact solver and two heuristics. I'd be interested in hearing how well this works for you!